# What does it mean when `ls` shows a numeric user id?

Tags: user-management

I'm fairly new to the ubuntu system. We have an Ubuntu server where we host our WordPress sites, and I have seen a lot of 1002 users when I do the `ls -lh` command inside a directory, like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1002 www-data 3.0K May 7 2014 wp-login.php
```

What is, or who is user `1002`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1002 is the UID for the user that owned the file.  Having a numerical value instead of a username means that the user that owns the file no longer exists in the /etc/passwd file.

If you run `cat /etc/passwd` you'll see a list of all the user accounts on the system.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
```

The first integer is the UID, or the user's unique numerical identification.  The second is the GUID, and this pertains to the user's primary group number.

Did you make any changes, or remove the user that owns the file from the system?