# Using tar command to backup file

Tags: command-line, backup, live-cd, tar, cd-command

I am using a **live cd** to take backup of a file.[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341620/is-it-possible-to-recover-files-owned-by-a-non-existing-owner) was my problem.

Now I want to use `tar` to backup a single file `Phone academics` where I have accumulated other files and I want to create the backup in the same folder`Phone cademics` at `/media/ubuntu/af89d536-745d-4899-971b-27cba56930be/alpha/Desktop/Phone academics`.

I changed the directory using `cd /media/ubuntu/af89d536-745d-4899-971b-27cba56930be/alpha/Desktop/Phone academics` which gives the result: 
`bash: cd: /media/ubuntu/af89d536-745d-4899-971b-27cba56930be/alpha/Desktop/Phone: No such file or directory`

So I opened terminal from the folder Phone academics so the directory changes to phone academics atomatically. Is this the right way to change? It now looks like:

[image]

If I use this code  `tar -cvf backupphoneacademics.tar/ media/ubuntu/af89d536-745d-4899-971b-27cba56930be/alpha/Desktop/Phone academics --exclude backupphoneacademics.tar` It gives: 
`tar: backupphoneacademics.tar/: Cannot open: Is a directory ; tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

What is wrong here? what do I do to take backup of that single file in the same folder?

Comment: Your `tar` command may have a mis-placed slash and a missing escape: `tar -cvf backupphoneacademics.tar /media/ubuntu/af89d536-745d-4899-971b-27cba56930be/alpha/Desktop/Phone\ academics --exclude backupphoneacsdemics.tar`

Comment: Oh thanks..that worked, however files were not backedup...permission denied `tar: backupphoneacademics.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: Where are you trying to save the `.tar` file? Is it a writable location? 

Comment: It is saved in a writable location but the location from which I am trying to take backups is not readable or writable..:/